# Access selected object property in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and I'm working with angular.js and angular-material together.

What I'm trying to do is create a md-select and assign an object to it as a ng-model. My md-options come from an array of objects, and when I select the desired option, the whole object is stored in the ng-model.

The problem is that when after that I try to select a property of this object, nothing is returned. You can see my code here:

```
<md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block col-1111-20-0-fl mrg-l-20">
      <md-select ng-model="orderItems[$index].item">
         <md-option ng-repeat="item in itemNames[$index] | orderBy: item.name" value="{{item}}">
           {{item.name}} - {{item.price | currency : 'R$' : 2}}
         </md-option>
       </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

    {{orderItems[$index].item.name}}
```

if I write just {{orderItems[$index].item}}, the whole object is accessed, showing it as an object and it's propeties, like this:

{"_id":"5812cfdb1c27a7187c61b8c1","price":"2","name":"Water Bottle 500ml"}

but when I write:

{{orderItems[$index].item.name}}

I can't access the name of the object, nothing shows.

What am I doing wrong here??

Thanks!

Comment: Could you try changing <md-option value="{{item}}"> to <md-option ng-value="item"> check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2f6qscrp/196/

Answer (score 0):

The `$index` you're using in the ng-repeat won't apply to the parent `md-select` so you cannot index your orderItems array using that number.  Also, according to the angular-material docs, you don't need to evaluate `value="{{item}}"` for the value attribute.

If you just want to store the value selected as an object, you can just do this:

```
<md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block col-1111-20-0-fl mrg-l-20">
  <md-select ng-model="selectedItem">
    <md-option ng-repeat="item in itemNames | orderBy: item.name" ng-value="item">
      {{item.name}} - {{item.price | currency : 'R$' : 2}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```